# Apply CssRules just for a specific element

Tags: javascript, html

```css
var css = "";
for (var j = 0; j < document.styleSheets.length; j++) {
    var cssRules = document.styleSheets[j].cssRules;
    for (var i = 0; i < cssRules.length; i++) {
        css += cssRules[i].cssText;
    }
}
```

I can get all css codes on a website with above code. How can apply it to a specific element

Comment: What exactly do you mean? Do you want to style one element with css?  Please elaborate on your question so we can help you.

Comment: I want to get all css codes of an element.

Comment: Possible duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2952667/find-all-css-rules-that-apply-to-an-element

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4482374/is-it-possible-to-find-css-rules-from-an-html-node-via-javascript

Comment: To add all css classes to an element you must use this syntax: `<HTMLElementObject>.className = class` where `class` is the name of the class. If you would add more than one class, separate them with spaces, like "test demo"