# How to get the CSS rules compatible with a node?

Tags: css, google-chrome, webkit

It's possible to know what CSS rules is applied to a specific node?

Example:

```
<div class="test-node">
  <strong>Test</strong>
</div>
```

And the CSS rules:

```
div           { color: blue }
div:hover     { color: green; }
.test-node    { font-weight: bold; }

div > strong  { color: red; }
```

So, the `div` node is affected by two rules `div` and `.test-node` and the `div:hover` if hover node only. The `strong` node is affected by `div` and `div:hover` rule, because it is inner a `div`, but the `color` property is overwrited by your own rule `div > strong` (example http://jsfiddle.net/yyf9v/).

Basically I need discovery how I can do the samething that *Chrome Inspector* does in javascript. If you use Chrome, go to Inspector (CTRL + Shift + J, Elements and select a node). You will se a *Styles* tab, that show `element.style` rule (attribute `style` basically) and the *Matched CSS Rules*... I need this!

Comment: "The `strong` node is affected by `div` and `div:hover` rule, because it is inner a `div`, but the `color` property is overwrited by your own rule `div > strong`." This is completely wrong; a `strong` element can **never** be affected by a rule that selects a `div`, because a `strong` is not a `div`!

Comment: Take a look please: http://jsfiddle.net/yyf9v/

Comment: That is inheritance; your `em` has no defined `color` rules so the default is to inherit from the `div`. It does not mean that the `div` selectors affect the `em`.

Comment: @DavidRodrigues Are you interested in *matched* rules only, or in both matched and *inherited* rules?

Comment: @ŠimeVidas both, but priority to matched rules

Comment: Read here: http://stackoverflow.com/q/2952667/425275

Answer (score 0):

why dont you try firebug on firefox ...  it is like the inspector in google chrome...

it shows all CSS classes applied for a specific node and what does it inherit and what is overriden.

you can find it here

http://getfirebug.com/

and here

https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/firebug/

Comment: I need do it on JS, specifically. Because I need this info inside my page.