# Element width in chrome using jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, google-chrome, firefox

I need element width before appending to body.

Following scripts is working fine in `firefox` but not in `google chrome`

```
<style>
 .testDiv { width:150px; height:100px; }
</style>

<script>
    var div = "<div class='testDiv'>Div Content</div>";
    alert($(div).width());
</script>
```

It gives output `150` in firefox and `0` in chrome

I have tried also

```
$(window).load(
   function() {
    alert($(div).width());
   }
);
```

But it is working same...

**UPDATE:**

I can see, if I declare `css inline` it works but it is needed to me using `css class`

```
var div = "<div style='width:150px;'>Div Content </div>";
alert($(div).width());
```

Comment: It may be because the div isnt present in the DOM yet. Try adding the div. Append()/ Prepend()/html() and then check the width

Comment: As per @SSS, you won't get a width until the element is inserted into the DOM

Comment: And BTW in the latest FF it isnt giving the width either.

Comment: @SSS It gives it for me on FF 29.0 Win7. But anyway, OP should add element to the DOM before getting any size. He could find some workaround as using a clone DIV and appending it outside of viewport, get the size and then remove the cloned element. It looks like FF 29.0 is applying CSS rules even element not in DOM, quite new for me

Comment: this [Link](http://jsfiddle.net/W4Km8/491/) shows and this [Link](http://jsfiddle.net/W4Km8/490/) not. becoz in crome style not render first.

Comment: @SSS Apparently because you didn't read the first sentence. To the actual solution, if you can't add and remove the element at the same time you need to go through your CSS rules by iterating over `document.styleSheets`. You can get inspiration in this similiar topic: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2952667/find-all-css-rules-that-apply-to-an-element

Comment: @SSS Because your pointer has been assigned to Adam Hopkinson

Comment: Try this one: `$(document).ready(function() { $('body').append("<div class='testDiv'>Div Content</div>"); alert($(".testDiv").width()); });`

Answer (score 0):

This may be the reason , if you have in-line css in your div say, it will display your width properly. probably css properties does not load in chrome

```
<script>
    var div = "<div style='width:150px' class='testDiv'>Div Content</div>";

$(window).load(
   function() {
    alert($(div).width());
   }
); 
</script>
```

Comment: Thanks @lampdev I have said this already in update but its not a proper solution always

Answer (score 0):

I think you can't do that in Chrome and I'm sure there is a good explanation but I don't know it. So here is my solution to that problem [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/uYm7a/2/) Append a div to the DOM with `display:none` and when you have the width remove it. The answer which @lampdev gave is also correct but it takes just the width from the style attribute. That is not the computed width and it will be wrong in many cases.

Answer (score 0):

You could try something like this:

```
var div = "<div class='testDiv'>Content</div>";
$(div).attr('id', 'test').css('position', 'fixed').appendTo('body');
console.log($("#test").width());
$("#test").remove();
```

This will give you the width without crashing your view and your div variable will still have the correct properties.