# How to get an element's "specified" style instead of computed style

Tags: javascript, css, mobile

On a web page that does not contain a `viewport` meta tag, most mobile browsers will "boost" some or all of the fonts on the page to a size larger than what the css specifies. On mobile Safari, for instance, a specified size of `7px` will be boosted to something like `12px`.

You can read out the boosted value by using [getComputedStyle](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window.getComputedStyle). My question is, is there a reliable way to read out the *unboosted* value? I.e. if the font is boosted to 12, I want to know that it started out at 7.

Comment: By specified style are you refering to the actual style that is either specified in the linked stylesheet or inside style tags?

Comment: Yup. I want the raw style, as specified in the stylesheet/style tag/inline, etc., vs. what the browser ends up rendering.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just a quick answer here. In short: you can't get specified styles with today's API's. I *was* able to solve my specific problem by temporarily turning off font-boosting by using [text-size-adjust](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/text-size-adjust) (prefixed with -webkit- for Safari).

Answer (score 0):

Webkit has a deprecated function to get all stylesheet rules for an element: `window.getMatchedCSSRules(<<element>>)`. You could use that to get the list of rules and loop through them to print or process the properties of each however you like. You would also need to consider the `style` attribute of the element.

To handle your `font-size` scenario, I imagine the best approach would be to get all the rules that apply to the element, order them by priority (remembering to factor in the `style` attribute and `!important` flags, and then pick out the value.

This isn't exactly *reliable* though, since it's a Webkit function and it's on its way out. There's [a bunch of discussion here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2952667/find-all-css-rules-that-apply-to-an-element) about how to fish out rules. Once you have the rules for an element, it's just a matter of picking out the specific information you need.