# Echo css style.overflow property with javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, overflow, echo

solved with @jcubic code: "To get the value use $("#expand"+idxpand).css('overflow');"

---

I want to get the property of overflow.

```
   alert(document.getElementById("expand"+idxpand).style.overflow);
```

Onclick if div overflow is set to  hidden, expand the content . If is not set to hidden, set to overflow:hidde.

```
 $('<div id="expand'+xpndid+'" style="position: relative;overflow-y: hidden;
max-height: 255px;"></div><a href="#" onclick="idxpand='+xpndid+';
expandimg();" >view photo</a>').prependTo('#mybox').hide().fadeIn('slow');
xpndid++; 
function expandimg(){
if (document.getElementById("expand"+idxpand).style.overflow == 'hidden')
    {
    //do things}
 else{
//set to hidden
}
}
```

I am unable to get the property. On alert I get empty value. Any idea?

Comment: probably ther style is applied through a stylesheet and is not added on the element's style property, use this http://stackoverflow.com/a/2953122/3591273

Comment: Maybe because you use an ' in your id. Thought you have to Note it like \'

Comment: Try to use jQuery `$("#expand"+idxpand).css('overflow', 'hidden')`

Comment: @jcubic I want to get the property, not to set. @ Nikos for alert(css(document.getElementById("expand0"))); in console log I get this error :Uncaught ReferenceError: css is not defined

Comment: To get the value use `$("#expand"+idxpand).css('overflow');`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think that you get the wrong element, try:

```
<a href="#" onclick="idxpand='\'+xpndid+\'';expandimg();" >view photo</a>
```

Comment: No need to escape quotes.

Comment: @CCA You have to because it's a string inside single quote.

Comment: And in this case? --- $('<div id="expand'+xpndid+'" style="position: relative;overflow-y: hidden;
max-height: 255px;"></div><a href="#" onclick="idxpand='+xpndid+';expandimg();" >view photo</a>').prependTo('#mybox').hide().fadeIn('slow'); xpndid++;

Comment: @CCD Thats completelly different code, it's not html anymore with id where you have single quote.

Comment: True, I will improve my question. Your code from the comment need to be in your answer "To get the value use $("#expand"+idxpand).css('overflow');" Thanks!!!