# Is this inline style or css file style returns with jquery .css()

Tags: jquery, css

I want to check right padding value of div element. I use jquery **.css()** method:

```
$('div').css('padding-right');
```

It works. Now I need to know where it value comes from. It can by inline defenition:

```
<div style="padding-right: 100px;">
```

or it can be wrote in external css file (or `<style></style>` section):

```
div {
    padding-right: 100px;
}
```

Thanks!

Comment: Inline style has priority over CSS class

Comment: You can inspect the element in developer tools in Chrome and add a break point on Attributes modification, and refresh the page. If the page 'freezes' on refresh then you'll see where the change came from if it was from javascript injection. If nothing happens, then it means that it was an inline style and it was there from the beginning...

Comment: See: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2952667/find-all-css-rules-that-apply-to-an-element

Comment: I know about priority. About dev tools too. Thanks. I need to know it from js/jquery.

Answer (score 4):

According to the [css()](http://api.jquery.com/css/) documentation

> Get the **computed** style properties

and

> Note that the **computed** style of an element may not be the same as the
> value specified for that element in a style sheet. For example,
> computed styles of dimensions are almost always pixels, but they can
> be specified as em, ex, px or % in a style sheet. Different browsers
> may return CSS color values that are logically but not textually
> equal, e.g., #FFF, #ffffff, and rgb(255,255,255).

Therefore, at the end, whether its from an inline style or a style sheet, it is the **computed** style.

Comment: Thanks. Any other way?

Comment: @Cypher, any other way? What do you mean. Any way to determine where the style came from?

Comment: @Cypher, you can do $(this).attr('style').indexOf('padding-right:'+$(this).css('padding-right')) > -1

Comment: @Cypher But the above is **so** horrible because it can break **so** easily or might even be wrong if the computed value was not in px for example

Comment: @Cypher Maybe if you can tell me more detail of why you need to do this so we can  work out a cleaner way or better approach

Answer (score 1):

Try using developer tools in your browser of choice.  Right click the div -> "inspect element" (or similar) and look at the CSS for that element.  Find your 'padding-right', and it should show you the source for that rule.

Comment: This is not what he meant. He wants to check this through jquery.

Comment: @dsaket I'm sorry, I don't understand.  OPs question clearly asks how to find the source for a CSS rule, which can't be done with jQuery.

Comment: @dsaket `Now I need to know where it value comes from`

Answer (score 1):

You can check if your element has inline styles testing "style" property of the DOM element

```
$("div")[0].style
```

Comment: It seems i can start from this. Thanks.