# How to Get Html's @Page CSS Values in Javascript?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

Let's say I create an html document in js:

```
var myHtmlDoc = document.createElement('html');
```

And then assign it is some html with '@page' defined:

```
myHtmlDoc.innerHTML = '<html><head><style>@page {size: 320mm 120mm;margin: 10mm;}</style></head><body></body></html>';
```

Spaced/indented html from above quote for readability:

```
<html>
    <head>
        <style>
            @page {
               size: 320mm 120mm;
               margin: 10mm;
            }
        </style>
    </head>

    <body>
    </body>
</html>
```

Let's say I want to get the "size" and "margin" values out of `myHtmlDoc` (which I won't be defining by hand) and assign them to variables. How would I do that with raw javascript and/or jQuery?

---

Attempted solutions:

Tried the solution shown in this [plunk](http://jsfiddle.net/HP326/6/) from the answer here: [Find all CSS rules that apply to an element](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2952667/find-all-css-rules-that-apply-to-an-element) - this causes an error if used with @page:

> Uncaught SyntaxError: Failed to execute 'matches' on 'Element': '@page' is not a valid selector.

Will be updating the question with things that work/don't work.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/754607/can-jquery-get-all-css-styles-associated-with-an-element http://stackoverflow.com/questions/324486/how-do-you-read-css-rule-values-with-javascript http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2952667/find-all-css-rules-that-apply-to-an-element

Comment: Thanks Serg, I am looking through the answers now. My concern is whether @page is supported in the regular manner.

Comment: That I do not know. Give it a try and let us know too. I don't know of any other way though.