# Getting the touched position in local coordinates of a transformed element

Tags: javascript, cross-browser, css-transforms, mathjs

I have an element which has been transformed with a `matrix3d` to give it perspective. It represents the screen of a handheld device.

There's a background image showing the handheld device itself, and this is not transformed. The element which holds this is positioned, and the screen element is positioned absolutely within it, at `left: 0; top: 0;`, and then transformed, with an origin in the top-left of the container. This was the easiest way for me to line it up perfectly with the background image (I used [this very handy tool](http://www.useragentman.com/matrix/) to come up with the matrix), and it moves the screen element away from the corner.

I want to be able to interact with the screen with mouse and touch events. To do this, on a click or touch event I need to find the coordinates in the local coordinate system of the screen element -- that is, the coordinates before the transform has taken place. In other words, when clicking the top-left of the handheld device's screen (which is *not* the top-left of its bounding box on the page!) I want `[0, 0]`, and when clicking the top right of the screen, which in this transform's case is actually further up on the page as well as to the right, I want `[untransformedWidth, 0]`.

Mouse events provide `offsetX` and `offsetY` which purportedly do exactly this (more on that below), but the touch events don't have these properties, so I need a way to calculate them myself.

Using [math.js](http://mathjs.org/index.html) I can feed in the transformation matrix and invert it. I have [some code to loop over the CSS rules](https://stackoverflow.com/a/36126329/496046) to get the `transform: matrix3d(...)` rule (I don't want to repeat it in my code if I don't have to), which I'll skip over -- I know it works because the numbers match the CSS.

Note that CSS has its matrix elements in column order, so `matrix3d(a, b, c, d, e, f, g, h, i, j, k, l, m, n, o, p)` looks in regular matrix notation like this:

```
┌            ┐
│ a  e  i  m │
│ b  f  j  n │
│ c  g  k  o │
│ d  h  l  p │
└            ┘
```

Meanwhile, math.js wants its matrices declared row by row, like `[[a, e, i, m], [b, f, j, n]...`.

So starting where I have a list of the number elements from inside the `matrix3d(...)` expression, in CSS order, I'm building and inverting the matrix like this:

```
var rows = [[], [], [], []];
for (var i = 0; i < elements.length; i++) {
  rows[i % 4][Math.floor(i / 4)] = elements[i];
}

var matrixTransform = math.matrix(rows);

var invertedMatrixTransform = math.inv(matrixTransform);
```

I then set up a mouse event handler on the screen element:

```
screen.addEventListener('mousedown', function (event) {
  var rect = container.getBoundingClientRect();
  var x = event.clientX - rect.left;
  var y = event.clientY - rect.top;
```

If I move a marker (relative to the container) to this point `[x, y]`, it appears exactly where I clicked. So I know this much is working. I then multiply a vector of these coordinates by the inverse transformation matrix:

```
  var vector = math.matrix([x, y, 0, 1]);
  var result = math.multiply(inverseMatrixTransform, vector);
```

If I move another marker (this one relative to the screen element) to the resulting vector's values `[result.get([0]), result.get([1])]` it moves to *roughly* the same position as the previous marker, but it's not quite right. It seems that the further from the origin I go, the more error there is, until it's really quite bad towards the right and bottom edges.

But then what if I check against `offsetX` and `offsetY`? Well, it turns out that the answer depends on the browser.

In Firefox, the coordinates found with `offset*` don't match the clicked position either. They're not quite the same as my calculated one, but only different by a couple of pixels. They're just as far away from the true clicked point as my calculated values.

[image: Sample output in Firefox 45]

But in Chrome the coordinates found with `offset*` are perfect.

[image: Sample output in Chrome]

Here's a [jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/gq1vLaxk/6/).

Is there anything I'm doing wrong with my calculation? Is there a way for me to mimic Chrome's result, but without the `offset*` properties?

Comment: I suspect the mismatch between `event.offset*` in Firefox and Chrome may be a bug. I've [reported it on the Firefox tracker](https://bugzilla.mozilla.org/show_bug.cgi?id=1261645). But if it *is* a Firefox bug, the same bug exists in my code, and I want to find it.

Comment: This bug seems to be fixed in Firefox version 50.0.2, although i'm still interested in what the actual solution was here.

Comment: Correction: i can confirm the bug is still there, my testing was wrong. Would be great if this gets solved.

Comment: Very frustrating, isn't it? Do my calculations look right to you? I wonder if it could be an inaccuracy of some kind in math.js... But much more likely something I've done wrong.

Comment: @tremby Did you find any solution or workaround?

Comment: @Dmitrijs Balcers, afraid not. It remains a mystery to me.

Comment: @DmitrijsBalcers, see below; there is now a solution!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I am not entirely sure about the theory, I read about this while I was working on a similar problem, but here is what I found. The multiplication of the matrices (the matrix of the 3d transformation - homogeneous coordinates, and the position of the cursor) produces two more values apart from x and y. The first is z, and the other one is w which is used in order to project the 3d object on a 2d plane.

If you divide the x and y values of the vector by the w coordinate, you get the correct position/mapping of the cursor on the Cartesian plane.

So, I would replace the code in your fiddle, lines 69-70, with these:

```
var x = result.get([0]);
var y = result.get([1]);
var w = result.get([3]);
screenCrosshair.style.left = x / w + 'px';
screenCrosshair.style.top = y / w + 'px';
```

Here is the update fiddle:
https://jsfiddle.net/x3ruc3tL/1/

And then you don't need the `offsetX` and `offsetY` values of the browser in order to find the correct position.

Please read the following articles for more information:

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/3D_projection#Perspective_projection
http://deltaorange.com/2012/03/08/the-truth-behind-homogenous-coordinates/

Comment: That's it! Thanks so much! It looks like Mozilla has the exact same bug in their code, so I'll direct them to your solution.