# Extracting entire CSS affecting a DIV on a web page

Tags: html, css

I wish to extract the entire CSS affecting a div that is highlighted. With complex designs the CSS is made up of many classes which add in some CSS. Looking for a technique that can strip out and perhaps concatenate all these together, like Inspect Element but cleaner.

For example, on this Adobe Experience Page(http://www.adobe.com/uk/products/experience-design.html). I wish to select the article div "A new experience in user experience." and then pull out all the CSS affecting everything inside it attached to a class.

There is an ExtractCSS tool that does something similar, but looking for something a bit more intuitive. That ignores all the strikethroughs too.

[image]

Comment: Questions asking us to suggest, find or recommend a book, tool, software library, plug-in, tutorial, explain a technique or provide any other off-site resource are off-topic for Stack Overflow Stack Overflow

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Find all CSS rules that apply to an element](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2952667/find-all-css-rules-that-apply-to-an-element)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The simplest way is:

- Select your element in the developer tools
- Run `window.getComputedStyle($0).cssText` on the Js console

where `$0` represents the currently selected DOM element.

In alternative, if you want to target a specific element with a given class, then do
`window.getComputedStyle( document.getElementsByClassName('hero2-align-2 hero2-basis-0')[0] ).cssText`
*Querying elements by class name might return more than 1 element, the `[0]` is there to guarantee only one is processed.*
Or by id
`window.getComputedStyle( document.getElementById('yourID') ).cssText`

Comment: Clicked on Inspect, then highlighted the article, then clicked on Console and tried "window.getComputedStyle(hero2-align-2 hero2-basis-0).cssText" which returns "Uncaught SyntaxError: missing ) after argument list"

Comment: @merch89 Please type `$0` instead of the class. You should type `window.getComputedStyle($0).cssText`.

Comment: @merch89 To understand what that dollar zero means, just type `$0` on the console, select another element, type again, select another element, type again...

Comment: That will give the values of the properties, but he wants the RULES which are being applied.