# Get static html / css snapshot of component

Tags: angular

In short: How do I get the generated CSS of my component as a string?

-> I want to get a snapshot of my component. That is, what the very view looks looks like. Just what you see when you click right->inspect. Html & css to render the component *independently* from any Javascript.

Motivation: Use that snapshot for later export as PDF. I could create the PDFs server-wise, but since Angular has a neat templating engine, why not use it for that? Comments welcome.

I managed to get the snapshot html code from my `banana`-component like this:

```ts
// banana component file
@Component( { 
    selector: 'banana',
    template: `<div id="report">some text</div>`,
    styles: [ '#report { font-weight:bold; }' ]
})
export class BananaComponent {
    constructor(public elementRef: ElementRef) { }
}

// parent component file
@Component(...)
export class App {
    @ViewChild(BananaComponent) myBanana;
    private getSnapshot() {
         let bananaSnapshotHtml = this.myBanana.elementRef.nativeElement.outerHTML;
         let bananaSnapshotCss = // ?? TODO
    }
}
```

The `snapshotHtml` variable for example looks like this:

```html
<banana _ngcontent-c2="" _nghost-c4="" ng-reflect-render="true"><!--bindings={
  "ng-reflect-ng-if": "true"
}--><div _ngcontent-c4="" id="report">
    some text
</div></banana>
```

But I have no idea how to get the respective `bananaSnapshotCss`. According to Firefox, Angular somehow puts this inline:

```css
#report[_ngcontent-c4] {
  font-weight: bold; 
}
```

Is there a way to get this ^ somehow programmatically? I want my `bananaSnapshotCss` variable above to hold this exactly. Or is my entire approach wrong?

Right now, I am manually copying the contents of my css-files into `bananaSnapshotCss` and thus, it is part of my TS code. This is ugly and duplicate code and ignores nested child component styles.

See live sample [here](http://plnkr.co/edit/cNLSTTSlTMqw8UlMeQEu?p=preview), including the current workaround (`app/app.ts` with a `TODO`)

Comment: I read question twice , I'm still not quite sure what do you want to achieve.

Comment: @Milad I'm really sorry. I tried rephrasing some parts. Maybe if you say where, I can elaborate.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is the solution I could come up with.

```
@Component(...)
export class App {
    @ViewChild(BananaComponent) myBanana;
    private getSnapshot() {
        let bananaSnapshotHtml = this.myBanana.elementRef.nativeElement.outerHTML;
        // new:
        let bananaSnapshotCss = [].slice.call(document.styleSheets)
            .map(sheet => [].slice.call(sheet.rules))
            .filter(sheet => !sheet.disabled)
            .reduce((all_rules, rules) => all_rules.concat(rules), [])
            .reduce((style, rule) => `${style}\n${rule.cssText}`, "");
    }
}
```

What this does is simply concatenating all `styleSheets` of the document. This will also contain CSS for other components. These could be filtered out but that is not really necessary.

Here is the updated plunker, if anybody is interested.  http://embed.plnkr.co/0BlyVihLcoDOLqzwqmNm/

With all of this, the component can finally be exported as a complete html file.

Comment: one could probably also work  with `ViewEncapsulation.Native` as another solution

Answer (score 3):

You can apply the `getComputedStyle()` method to `elementRef.nativeElement` (read more about it [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/getComputedStyle)).

For your example this would mean:

```js
// banana component file
@Component( { 
    selector: 'banana',
    template: `<div id="report">some text</div>`,
    styles: [ '#report { font-weight:bold; }' ]
})
export class BananaComponent {
    constructor(public elementRef: ElementRef) { }
}

// parent component file
@Component(...)
export class App {
    @ViewChild(BananaComponent) myBanana;
    private getSnapshot() {
         let bananaSnapshotHtml = this.myBanana.elementRef.nativeElement.outerHTML;
         let bananaSnapshotCss = getComputedStyle(this.myBanana.elementRef.nativeElement);
    }
}
```

Comment: please correct me if I'm wrong, but this does not seem to get the styling for the entire component recursively: Only for the component element itself. Meaning, the style definitions of everything **IN** the element is nowhere to be found, making this approach useless. At leasts it seems so: `getComputedStyle(...).cssText` does not contain any `color: yellow` for my `<p>` inside the banana component. Thanks anyway!

Comment: You would have to select the element you are interested in and traverse it's children. But the styles you extract are going to be really verbose. Maybe one of the solutions from http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2952667/find-all-css-rules-that-apply-to-an-element could help you?

Answer (score 2):

If you can generate PDF on client side, I would suggest to use a CSS media query: `@media print { ... }`

The main reason is that DOM doesn't reflect *"application"* state. Only re-rendering exported DOM isn't compliant. More your component CSS won't be enough to reproduce all styles (agent, page, component imbrication, and so on).

Most tool that have server-side web-based rendering (PDF, images, ...) are using [PhantomJS](http://phantomjs.org/) to generate a *"snapshot"*.

In the case of Angular, you can also take a look at [Angular Universal](https://universal.angular.io/) that offer server-side rendering.

Comment: huh. wrapping the component inside a `@media print` block and simply pressing ctrl+p might actually be the sanest approach here (however it gives you non-reusable PDF instead "exporting" the HTML)

Answer (score 1):

In your `@Component` selector add a class using `host: {'class':'reports'}` . Then in your css you can set styles using the reports class. Hope this helps you

Comment: I'm afraid I dont quite get it. How can I use this to get the CSS (either source or ng-generated) of my `<report/>`-component? I want to append it to the static html and create a downloadable file out of it.

Answer (score 1):

Use document.documentElement.innerHTML get the the whole DOM with inline css and save.

Comment: ..which would get me the markup for the entire website, when I only want a specific component. So you're saying the preferred way would be to extract the inline-css via regex or similar?