# Is there a way to find all HTML elements that use viewport units in their styles?

Tags: javascript, css, dom

I'm building an editor tool that for some features it needs to resize / zoom out the viewport to show more sections on the page.

I don't control the input of HTML/CSS/JS
All the CSS is external CSS from a `link` tag

The problem is HTML elements using `vh` as `height` or `min-height` in their styles.

is it possible to search the DOM for elements that have `vh` styles assigned?

I tried using `getComputedStyle` but as the function name suggests, it returns "computed" styles so for example if I have a section with `height` of `80vh`

```
getComputedStyle(el).height
// will return the computed value which is on my screen "655.2px"
```

What I'm hoping to achieve is to find those elements and assign them the computed values temporarily during the "zoomed out" view.

As i mentioned above the styles are external so using the `style` property won't provide what I'm looking for.

Comment: This [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/22638396/4604701) might help you.

Comment: Having worked on such projects myself you are probably best off working with computed style. Not entirely clear what the higher level issue is. A demo would help

Answer (score 0):

After some research and thanks to fubar's [comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53037889/is-there-a-way-to-find-all-html-elements-that-use-viewport-units-in-their-styles#comments-53037889) for pointing me to an [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2952667/find-all-css-rules-that-apply-to-an-element/22638396#22638396) using `document.styleSheets` I was able to come up with a solution that fulfils my need.

```
function findVhElements() {
    const stylesheets = Array.from(document.styleSheets)
    const hasVh = str => str.includes('vh');
    // this reducer returns an array of elements that use VH in their height or min-height properties 
    return stylesheets.reduce( (acc,sheet) => { 
        // Browsers block your access to css rules if the stylesheet is from a different origin without proper allow-access-control-origin http header
        // therefore I skip those stylesheets 
        if (!sheet.href || !sheet.href.includes(location.origin)) return acc
        // find rules that use 'vh' in either 'minHeight' or 'height' properties
        const targetRules = Array.from(sheet.rules).filter( ({style}) => style && (hasVh(style.minHeight) || hasVh(style.height)) )
        // skip if non were found
        if (!targetRules.length) return acc;
        // return elements based on the rule's selector that exits on the current document 
        return acc.concat(targetRules.map( ({selectorText}) =>  document.querySelector(selectorText) ).filter( el => el) ) 
    }, [])
}
```

This solution works for my case because the styles are coming from the same origin as the script, if you are dealing with styles from other origins I would suggest either implementing a backend solution or making sure that the other origin is providing HTTP headers that allows you to fetch it's content