# get <style> or <link> element that defines a given CSS class

Tags: css, dom, cssom

Let's say I have

```
<head>
  <style type="text/css" id="style1">
    .foo {
      ...
    }
  </style>
  <style type="text/css" id="style2">
    .bar {
      ...
    }
  </style>
</head>
<body>
  <div class="foo">
  </div>
</body>
```

In the Chrome DevTools, the style inspector for the `<div class="foo">` element will have a link to the `<style id="style1">` tag where `.foo` is defined.

Is there any DOM API to look this up efficiently?

The only way I can think of to find the `<style>` element is an inefficient, brute-force search like this:

```
function findStyleElementForClass(cls) {
  if (!cls.startsWith('.')) cls = '.' + cls
  for (var i = 0; i < document.styleSheets.length; i++) {
    var sheet = document.styleSheets[i]
    var rules = sheet.rules || sheet.cssRules
    for (var j = 0; j < rules.length; j++) {
      if (rules[j].selectorText === cls) {
        return sheet.ownerNode
      }
    }
  }
}
findStyleElementForClass('foo')
```

Or is there a proposal anywhere for a new DOM/CSSOM API to do this lookup?

Comment: Questions asking us to suggest, find or recommend a book, tool, software library, plug-in, tutorial, explain a technique or provide any other off-site resource are off-topic for Stack Overflow Stack Overflow

Comment: OP asks about technique to retrieve source stylesheet participating on styling concrete HTML element OR (exsitence of) standard (proposal) allowing such operation, I think it is perfectly valid question. Related / possible duplicate: https://stackoverflow.com/q/2952667

Comment: @myf I hadn't found that question, I added my vote to close this as a duplicate