# Detect !important css rule of separate DOM element with JS

Tags: javascript, css

How could I detect !important rule of style property for directed DOM element?

ex:

```
<div class = "class">
***content***
</div>

.class{
top: 45px!important; 
}

let elmStyles = document.getElementsByClassName('class')[0].style;
/* i need this =====> */  let isImportant = elmStyles.getPropertyPriority("top");
```

I`ve found some info about that, but I can not apply it for concrete DOMelement
https://developer.mozilla.org/ru/docs/Web/API/CSSStyleDeclaration/getPropertyPriority

Comment: `CSSStyleDeclaration` operates on the _declaration_ level, nomen est omen, you can not “apply” that for a specific DOM element.

Comment: You can perhaps try and get all declarations that apply to the element first, https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2952667/find-all-css-rules-that-apply-to-an-element - but I guess then you would still have to figure out which actually apply based on specificity, if multiple rules set a value for the same property.

Answer (score 0):

You can find all the elements to which `top` and that particular class which `.class` is applied to

Means you need to loop through all the rules and find the corresponding class for it

```
var declaration = document.styleSheets;
for(var i=0;i<declaration.length;i++) {
    for(var j=0;j<declaration[i].cssRules.length;j++) {
        var rule = declaration[i].cssRules[j];
        if(rule.style.getPropertyPriority("top")=="important") {
            var selector = rule.selectorText;
            if(selector[0]==".") {
                var elements = document.getElementsByClassName(selector.substring(1));
                for(var k=0;k<elements.length;k++) {
                    var element = elements[k];
                    console.log(element)
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

this loop will loop through all rules and find `top` is marked as `!important`

Then select all elements to which the `class` is applied and print in the console

Currently I have written only for `class`, for `ID` and `tag name` this is code will not work