# Complete copy of a css rule to another with HTML editing only

Tags: html, css

I have this line of code:

```
<i aria-hidden="true" class="tb-icon tb-icon-account"></i>
```

The change i want to make is exatly this:

```
<span aria-hidden="true" class="tb-icon tb-icon-account"></span>
```

The hard part (if there is a way) is that i want the browser to see the change as it is, but take all the css rule of an `<i>` tag. I dont want to change the css file so i was wondering if can point somehow to the css rule like it was before the change.

Comment: You can not make any rules that use the `i` element selector, match a `span` instead. You would need to go through all your rules, find the ones that apply based on an `i` selector, and modify or clone them, with the `i` replaced with `span` ... that _could_ be done using JavaScript, but it will get complex - and quite frankly, based on your description so far I can't even see what purpose this was actually supposed to serve.

Comment: @CBroe But you can actually do just that: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2952667/find-all-css-rules-that-apply-to-an-element

Comment: Not with HTML editing only

Comment: Using the `i` tag for icons is way cooler, though. Which IDE do you use? Basically all of them help you with refactoring your code nowadays.