# getComputedStyle: how to get the height defined on CSS instead of the actual rendered height?

Tags: javascript, css, styles, getcomputedstyle

I have this code:

```
<style>

    #div {
        height: 100px;
        background-color: #A00;
    }

    .short {
        max-height: 0px;
    }
</style>

<div id="div" class="short"></div>

<script>

    var div = document.getElementById("div");
    var computed = window.getComputedStyle(div);
    console.log(computed.height); //... I expected 100px instead of the value for max-height definition.

</script>
```

I know that the max-height limits the height, but how do I get the "height" definition instead of the rendered value?

Comment: you can access the css poperty like this in your script. `div.style.height` .

Comment: div.style.height returns null, because it only handles in-line style definition. And in this example, there is none.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We can read the CSS stylesheet rules of the document (`document.styleSheets`, [see MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/styleSheets)) and extract rules with the selector text of `#div` and then use the first height value.
The first item should be the highest prioritized style.

We iterate through all of the styles until we get a result that isn't an empty string, otherwise the function could break in the sense that another `#div` style without a `height` property would still be prioritized over a previously defined `#div` style *with* a `height` property.

Using the function provided at: https://stackoverflow.com/a/22638396/20073186

```js
function css(el) {
    var sheets = document.styleSheets, ret = [];
    el.matches = el.matches || el.webkitMatchesSelector || el.mozMatchesSelector 
        || el.msMatchesSelector || el.oMatchesSelector;
    for (var i in sheets) {
        var rules = sheets[i].rules || sheets[i].cssRules;
        for (var r in rules) {
            if (el.matches(rules[r].selectorText)) {
                ret.push(rules[r]);
            }
        }
    }
    return ret;
}
```

We can look specifically for the `#div` styling, and if we can't find it (or a height value), use the computed styling:

```js
function getStylesheetHeight(element, selectorText) {
    const rules = css(element);
    const selectorRules = rules.filter((rule) => rule.selectorText == selectorText);

    let height = null;

    for(let index = 0; index < selectorRules.length; index++) {
        if(!selectorRules[index].style.height.length)
            continue;

        height = selectorRules[index].style.height;

        break;
    }

    return height ?? element.style.height;
};
```

And use it as such:

```js
const element = document.getElementById("div");

function css(el) {
    var sheets = document.styleSheets, ret = [];
    el.matches = el.matches || el.webkitMatchesSelector || el.mozMatchesSelector 
        || el.msMatchesSelector || el.oMatchesSelector;
    for (var i in sheets) {
        var rules = sheets[i].rules || sheets[i].cssRules;
        for (var r in rules) {
            if (el.matches(rules[r].selectorText)) {
                ret.push(rules[r]);
            }
        }
    }
    return ret;
};

function getStylesheetHeight(element, selectorText) {
    const rules = css(element);
    const selectorRules = rules.filter((rule) => rule.selectorText == selectorText);

    let height = null;

    for(let index = 0; index < selectorRules.length; index++) {
        if(!selectorRules[index].style.height.length)
            continue;

        height = selectorRules[index].style.height;

        break;
    }

    return height ?? element.style.height;
};

console.log(getStylesheetHeight(element, "#div"));
```

```css
#div {
    height: 100px;
    background-color: #A00;
}

.short {
    max-height: 0px;
}
```

```html
<div id="div" class="short"></div>
```

It's important to note that if the selector text would e.g. be `body #div`, then it would go uncaught by this function. You could work around this by replacing `rules.filter((rule) => rule.selectorText == selectorText)` with `rules.filter((rule) => rule.selectorText.endsWith(selectorText))` but this could potentionally be misleading.